# Moving characters with Xtiled in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently starting some projetcs in XNA C#, since I'm programming in C for a few years now and I want to get some thing to become serious.

So, I started this project of a simple, 2D RPG game, using Tiled Map Editor to create my maps, and the framework Xtiled to import them and draw them in my screen game.

But I'm lacking of some essential tips. I can draw a character at the screen but there is no way I can sync it with my map !

I just know how to draw it like you'll draw anything in the screen game with XNA.
I would be really happy if someone could explain me how to get started with it, to see something like, at what tile my character is every time it moves.

The answer may not be very complicated, I actually just think when I'm going see the answer I'll tell myself "I knew this".

Answer (score 0):

> what tile my character is everytime it moves.
>
> no way I can sync it with my map

If you used a starter kit, you should see a collision.cs file. This is the logic that determines where your player is and what it's currently colliding with.

There are many tutorial sites which you can help you further with this. Checkout this site: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

Comment: Thanks for your link. No i didn't use any starter kit, only the XNA project and the combo TiledMap Editor / Xtiled to get my maps in tiled maps and then draw it in the screen.